# Creating a loop for a range of rows for a code that runs for a single row

Tags: vba, excel, loops, range

I am building a macro which will create an automatic report (the name of the report sheet is "RCCP INPUT"), by extracting data from another worksheet (source which is named "CW33 17"). I have build the code that runs for a single row of the source sheet, so it creates the report for only one row (every row represents an order). I want to have a report for a range of rows so I need to extend my code to apply for a range of rows. So, lets say that this range is called myRange and it includes rows 2 to 70. So, my report must have all these rows. My code is provided below. I have included the headers too, so the report starts from row 2. The row that the macro runs for, for now is row 2. Just to clarify it more, the report must have each row that is selected from the source  multiplied by 6 (6 copies, one below the other) as it can be seen from the macro below, because in the Forecast column and Forecast Quantity column, each order(row) must have values for 6 weeks. I hope I have clarified it well! Any ideas how to make it work?.. I have failed miserably so far.. Much appreciated!

The report looks like this (for one row - as it is multiplied by 6) and the other rows should be placed in the same way underneath.

[image: Report interface for one row]

```
Sub RCCP_INPUT()

Sheets("RCCP INPUT").Select

    range("C1").Value = "T-Lane ID"                    'Column C
    range("D1").Value = "Week of RCCP"                 'Column D
    range("E1").Value = "Forecast"                     'Column E
    range("F1").Value = "Forecast Quantity"            'Column F

    Sheets("CW33 17").Select
    range("D2:E2").Copy
    Sheets("RCCP INPUT").Select
    range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Dim rws As Long
    With range("A2:B2")
    rws = .Rows.Count
    .Resize(rws).Copy Destination:=.Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 5)
    End With
    range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
    With range("C2")
    rws = .Rows.Count
    .Resize(rws).Copy Destination:=.Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 5)
    End With
    Sheets("CW33 17").Select
    range("G2:L2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("RCCP INPUT").Select
    range("F2:F7").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone,   SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Sheets("RCCP INPUT").Select
    i = 1
    For Each cell In range("E2:E7")
        cell.Value = "Week +" & i
        i = i + 1
    Next cell
    Sheets("RCCP INPUT").Select
    range("E2").Value = Sheets("CW33 17").range("G2").Value - 1
    With range("E2")
    rws = .Rows.Count
    .Resize(rws).Copy Destination:=.Offset(rws).Resize(rws * 5)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: "I have failed miserably so far.. to find answers to my question on SO". Looking at your profile, you hardly ever accept any answer.

Comment: I see that you are using my answer in this code.  Yet you did not accept my answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner I upvoted the comment :) its was really helpful! how can I accept it besides upvoting?

Comment: @PericlesFaliagas on your last question since you obviosly think I gave the correct answer you would click the check mark by the answer accepting it as correct.  You should go back through all your questions and mark the correct answer.  People will stop helping without that feedback.

Comment: I am sorry my friend! I didnt do it on purpose.. I didnt even know that there was such thing besides upvoting for something! I might have done what you said but definitely by mistake, so I wasnt aware of this thing existing. I willl give you feedback right away!.. sorry!

Answer (score 0):

In order to generalize your code you need to move away from absolute addresses somehow.  One way is to assign ranges and then offset them as needed to get to the positions you need. The code below runs through `numNeeded` number of times and keeps adding directly below as you mention.  I don't know anything about the source data after the first time through so it just repeats the first set of data right now.  But you can draw new data from different sheets or use offsets on the source sheet to grab new data for each time through. I've put many `r.select` statements in the code so that you can step through and easily see what the code is doing, but these should be removed once you understand.

```
Sub reportGen()
  Dim destSh As Worksheet, sourceSh As Worksheet
  Dim sourceR1 As Range, sourceR2 As Range
  Dim r As Range, pasteR As Range
  Const numNeeded = 10
  Set sourceSh = Worksheets("CW33 17")
  Set sourceR1 = sourceSh.Range("D2:E2")
  Set sourceR2 = sourceSh.Range("G2:L2")
  Set destSh = Worksheets("RCCP INPUT")
  Set r = destSh.Range("A1").Offset(7 * j, 0)
  r.Select
  r.Offset(0, 2) = "T-Lane ID"
  r.Offset(0, 3) = "Week of RCCP"
  r.Offset(0, 4) = "Forecast"
  r.Offset(0, 5) = "Forecast Quantity"
  For j = 0 To numNeeded
    Set r = destSh.Range("A2").Offset(j * 6, 0)
    r.Select
    sourceR1.Copy
    destSh.Paste
    Set pasteR = Selection
    pasteR.AutoFill destSh.Range(pasteR, pasteR.Offset(5, 0))
    Set r = r.Offset(0, 2)
    r.Select
    r.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-2],RC[-1])"
    r = r.Value
    r.AutoFill destSh.Range(r, r.Offset(5, 0))
    Set r = r.Offset(0, 3)
    r.Select
    sourceR2.Copy
    r.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    Set r = r.Offset(0, -1)
    r.Select
    For i = 1 To 6
      r.Offset(i - 1, 0) = "Week +" & i
    Next i
    r = sourceR2(1) - 1
    r.AutoFill destSh.Range(r, r.Offset(5, 0))
    r.Select
  Next j
End Sub
```

(By the way, I think there might be a mistake starting after your `For Each cell...` loop since it writes over data, but I wasn't sure so just kept it the way you have it)